# [This will be an answer], answering and clarifying questions as <50 rep users

Tags: discussion

It has been discussed and proposed hundreds of times and is asked about periodically on the meta, the fact that sub-50-rep-users can't comment. I propose a non-invasive way to resolve the problem.

### My proposal

**So my proposal is**, that we allow people with less than 50-rep to commit to answering a question by posting an answer beginning with

> [This will be an answer]
>
> Can you give a detail about what xy you are using ?
>
> Do you use cholate or vanilla ice cream to coffinate your coffeestream ?

This would act as a "under construction"-sign for 5-10 minutes after creation of the answer.
After clarification is given they can then edit out that part and will leave a normal looking answer behind and noone will notice that part ever existed and no new feature need to be implemented. If their answer is good, they worked their way towards the 50-rep and will only have to use this once or twice until they get the privilege to comment. If they fail to deliver an answer even after clarification, people downvote and flag, and the user will work his way towards an answer ban.

I ask this on SO, because this is probably most relevant here as this is the hardest community to get rep, the fastests to flag answers that should be comments.

Do you think this is a reasonable proposal or totally useless/wrong ? I personally think this would enable new users a smoother start and will give beginners that ask questions more answers and/or feedback to how to improve questions, while providing other beginners with the chance to answer more questions.

Comment: You say it's non-invasive - but it basically *is* invasive, because it leaves non-answers as if they were answers, on the *expectation* that they'll always be turned into answers... with edits that remove all of the original content. I suspect that a lot of the time, the OP wouldn't bother responding, leaving the cruft until the question is closed/deleted. Sounds like a bad idea to me.

Comment: People can downvote as soon as they see it, and later remove their downvotes if the answer is edited and good, if it isn't edited within 5-10 minutes it can simply be flagged. But the downvotes should be enough to prevent overuse of that "feature" because of answer bans.

Comment: Downvoting or not, getting rid of a garbage answer is much more difficult than of a garbage comment. If we want under-50 rep users to be able to comment, we should allow them to simply use the comment feature

Comment: Sounds like a lot of workarounds for something that I really don't see as a significant problem. If you have less than 50 rep and you encounter a question you can't answer without more information, just move on to a different question.

Comment: I just think that people a % of beginners will always circument that comment limitation, as there are dozens/hundreds of meta questions about that and it always occurs since the beginning of SO. Giving them a clear cut guideline of "only do this if you really know the answer for sure" would yield less or the exact same amount of work, but a better outcome in my oppinion.

Comment: The clear cut guideline is "don't do that" and the response is simple - flagging as "not an answer". Seems fine to me.

Comment: Everyone that is 50+ rep went through the same thing as you @HopefullyHelpful. And you're almost there ;) patience

Comment: This exact kind of feature misuse is _the reason why_ commenting is a privilege.

Answer (score 24):

This doesn't feel like a good idea at all, as it will break basically all mechanisms currently in place to keep the quality level high for both questions and answers. And that really is why Stack Overflow ranks highly in Google search, and why so many users visit Stack Overflow, which generates enough revenue to keep the servers running, and pay the bills and the devs.

You seem to suggest that it is a problem that you can't comment when you don't have 50 reputation yet. You propose to fix that.

I don't think that questions that are unclear should get any answer or for that matter any comment. Instead, those questions should be down-voted and closed as quickly as possible. That places a notice on the question for the asker that gives them guidance on how they should improve their question.

If you would allow what you propose, we should also drop voting on that answer, stop submitting those answers to the First Post review queue, and maybe change the order of answers as viewed to favor 'real' answers vs 'comment' answers.

One of the reasons for the reputation limit is to force new users to learn the mechanics of this site first. That forces you to learn which questions are answerable, and are therefore good questions. We don't cater to anyone and at any rate. As a community, we should strive to maintain high quality questions with high quality answers, where quality is determined by community voting.

The reputation limit is a barrier, but not one that is really high IMHO. Provide a handful of good answers or questions and some approved suggested edits, and you'll be at that level.

tl;dr: we shouldn't allow non-answers / under-construction answers, as it defeats the mechanism in place to guarantee some of our quality control.