# Add rationale to "comment everywhere"-privilege in help center

Tags: feature-request, comments, privileges, help-center

**Please read before marking as duplicate**

I experienced the same frustration (with not being able to comment under 50 rep) as a lot of other people.
The [help](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) page on this only mentions that it's a privilege.

1. *Why am I not allowed to ask more info from people who need help?*

   - [50 reputation points to make comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252133/50-reputation-points-to-make-comments)
   - [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)
   - [this-will-be-an-answer-answering-and-clarifying-questions-as-50-rep-users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303487/this-will-be-an-answer-answering-and-clarifying-questions-as-50-rep-users)

All give good answers *why*, but I'm not asking for a *why*.

[The privilege help page](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) doesn't mention a *why*, spawning all these duplicates of "why can't I comment", hence the frustration with this post.
So I'm asking to include these answers — or some similar explanation — on the help page so that people who are following the correct route to their answer can find it faster.

Comment: Why the downvote? I'm not asking why, I'm just asking to make it easier for people who are searching the same answer as me.

Comment: Pretty sure you got the downvote because the initial post sounded a lot like just more complaining of the same type we've all seen a lot of. That's not actually the case, but it wasn't as clear as it could have been.

Comment: Thank you for the edit, I didn't know how to put it clearer. I thought that was the reason so I clarified because I was afraid of losing the reputation that was my initial concern. Turned out to be another question asked numerous times.

Comment: Actually, rene's answer that you linked to doesn't really explain why at all. [Here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252133) has closer answers.

Comment: [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Comment: See my edit for why this is not a duplicate of "why can't I comment".

Comment: I have little faith that adding something to the help centre would substantially reduce the duplicates; but I applaud your optimism.

Comment: Of course there will be still people doublé posting. But every chunck of double posts you can avoid by a more complete help page is good

Comment: I get - this being posted so many times before - people marking it as a duplicate but I really don't know how I should make it more clear that this is not a duplicate.

Comment: @turoni it's clear enough (compared to the first revision), don't worry

Comment: A lot of us are jaded towards the idea that anything might slow the tide of duplicates, homework questions, and the other muck that appears daily. If the OP's idea will even prevent one dupe "why can't I comment?" post in the future, I say, *do it*.

Comment: @Jonharper But, what if there is some pascal programmer out there waiting for this change to occur.  Once this change occurs, they will unleash a tsunami of bot-controlled newbie accounts that will ddos meta with "why can't I comment?" duplicates.  Near infinite negative utility!  [Can we afford to wager than no such (pascal, or other language) programmer exists?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal's_Wager)  ;)

Comment: @Yakk Ironically, there's a Perl programmer who was waiting for just your comment...

Comment: @JonHarper Oh yes, the famous [Perl's wager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl's_Wager).  I thought that one was debunked?

Comment: I don't believe there's such a page.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski How is this gonna go further? Is there a certain amount of upvotes this'll get implemented? Is there anything I can do to 'promote' this without bumping this up with unnecessary comments?

Comment: @turoni you've tagged this as [feature-request], and got a very positive response. There's not much more you can do at this point besides waiting for an answer from the SO staff, but I figure it won't be very high priority on their to do list. BTW comments don't bump posts (editing a post does bump it though).

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Okay thanks for the info. I guess needles editing is also frowned upon? So my hypothetical best option would be placing a bounty on this?

Comment: @turoni if you have a constructive edit, then go ahead, but don't do it needlessly. You can't place bounties on meta, so that's not an option. Really, there'not much to do. If you're impatient you could try to find a community manager on the SO chat though, but try not to be annoying :)